# Custom NSView with NSTextField subview drawing issue

Tags: cocoa, drawing, nsview, nswindow

So I am drawing a custom window (transparent) with a custom NSView as the contentview, and wouldlike to add an NSTextField to the window as well, however, when I add the NSTextField, I get a weird resizing or redraw of the custom NSView, and I can't figure out what is causing the problem. Both the window and the contentview of the window are subclasses of NSWindow, and NSView, respectively. Also, I have tried to just layer the custom NSView (not set it as the contentview) with no change. Any ideas?

```
    NSWindow *quickEntryWindow = [[TransparentWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect([[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.width/2 - 250, [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.height/2 + 50, 500, 100) 
                                                            styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                                                              backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered 
                                                                defer:NO
                                                              special:YES];
    BorderView *quickEntryBorderView = [[BorderView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, [[quickEntryWindow contentView] frame].size.width, [[quickEntryWindow contentView] frame].size.height)];
    [quickEntryBorderView canDrawConcurrently];
    [quickEntryWindow setContentView:quickEntryBorderView];
    NSTextField *quickEntryTextField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, 10, [quickEntryBorderView frame].size.width-20, [quickEntryBorderView frame].size.height-20)];
    [quickEntryTextField setAutoresizingMask:NSViewNotSizable];
    [quickEntryTextField setBordered:NO];
    [quickEntryTextField setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [quickEntryTextField setFocusRingType:NSFocusRingTypeNone];
    [quickEntryTextField setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:42]];
    [quickEntryTextField setTextColor:[NSColor grayColor]];
    [quickEntryBorderView addSubview:quickEntryTextField];
```

What I get is something that looks like this (it is normal when no text is entered into the NSTextField):
[image]

Oh yeah, I know I'm not managing my memory...I'm just trying to get this working. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a description or example of what it *should* look like? And what makes the resizing or redrawing "weird"? (e.g. "Normally it would draw like ... but instead it's flickering every time I resize the window...")

Comment: Normally it just looks like the outermost window. There should not be a border drawn around the text field.

Comment: I'm also having this problem with nstextfields placed in custom views.  It goes away if you tell your parent view to display. It has something to do with the focus ring. Btw, if you turn on interior focus ring, the second smaller rounded box does not appear, and it looks a little less horrible.

Comment: I discovered the problem went away if I inherited from nsbox instead of nsview.

Comment: to clarify, the problem is with nstexttfields whose backgrounds and focus rings are turned off and that are editable when placed in custom view classes. It also affects nstextviews which have their background (and their scrollview's background) turned off. The symptom is a rounded rectangle being drawn around the text in the textview when you click in it. The first time you click, the bounds of the spurious rect are what the focus ring rect would be. When defocus and then click again,the bounds are of the text. The problem goes away if you subclass nsbox for your custom view